# Elastic Search multi match

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to ElasticSearch. Now I have a requirement that need to return all result which contains the keyword.

```
public Class People(){
    public string UserId {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

I want to filter all People if one of three fileds contains the keyword, similar to **like "%keyword%"**.

For example,I have a People

```
var people = new People() {
    UserId = "lastname.middlename.firstname",
    FirstName = "firstname",
    LastName = "lastname"
}
```

How I could get this Peoplle by searching the keyword **ddl**, How to setup the index and how to query.

I have tried to query with NEST like below

```
  var keyword = "ddl"
  var result = await _client.SearchAsync<People>(s => 
      s.Query(q => q.MultiMatch(m => m.Fields(f => f.Field(ff => ff.UserId).Field(ff => ff.FirstName).Field(ff => ff.LastName)).Query(keyword)))
  );
```

It won't work. It only work when I changed the keyword to **firstname** or **lastname** or **lastname.middlename.firstname**

Is there any way to meet the requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you would want to configure an analyzer for each of the target fields that tokenizes terms into trigrams, probably using the [ngram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) with `min_gram` and `max_gram` set to 3. This analysis will generate a `ddl` token for `middlename` that would then match your query.

The longer answer is that you'll want to have a read about [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html), and how to [write](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html) and [test analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/testing-analyzers.html) with the .NET client. You may want to go through [the example repository that builds a Nuget search application](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example). It's a fairly involved walkthrough that goes through a number of concepts, including analysis.

Comment: is there any query method that just return matched original terms, not synonyms or something else?

Answer (score 0):

To search on parts of your fields, you should use an [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) in your mapping.

It will tokenize your fields using windows of different size.

This should solve your problem, but you need to take care of several points :

- It is likely that you will want to use this analyzer only at index time. Using this tokenizer both at indexation and search is likely to generate a **LOT** of irrelevant results.
- Use a minimum window size (`min_gram` parameter) not to low. In your case 3 will work.
- The size of your index can substantially grow.

Another solution, simpler to implement but usually not efficient is to use [wildcards queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) in query string. It is very similar to the **LIKE** operator in SQL.